# How to use PayPal for web application just to do payment, not like buying order

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Actually I am developing an Healthcare webapplication, which need to have patient payment to their bill. Which method of PayPal payment to use, or how to do payment thro' PayPal.
I have implemented basic PayPal payment using BuyNow button suggest in [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers). It is working fine, but in PayPal payment page having "Order Summary" before payment, "Thanks for your Order" after payment[image] looking like shopping payment, I googled to change them and failed. Is there any other method for just doing bill payment, which suits my requirement. Or how can I change the above mentioned payment method to my requirements.
Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a way to change major things in that checkout page. [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) allows for a user to sign in to their PayPal account. All it would say is that they will be paying you. Then they would redirect back to your app and you can submit to process the payment.

It's a little more involved of an integration than a simple button but that sounds more like what you are looking for.
The other option is using the [Invoicing API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/invoicing/).

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: I'd say that Express Checkout should do everything you need, IIRC it can get Paypel to return to your site so that you can display an order summary and Confirm button, and can return to your site afterwards for the thankyou page. They also have an instant payment notification service (IPN) that you can implement to allow payment status to be communicated to your database, without relying upon the customer's browser requesting the thank you page. IPN works with Paypal Direct too.

Comment: Now in the method i m using also have the same logic, i m passing returnURL, after PayPal payment its returning my website after thanku page, everything is fine. The problem is the label "Order" before and after payment. As u suggest i can check with Express Checkout.

Comment: Mark Robjohn is correct.  Express Checkout will do what you need.  But you will be responsible for doing the "Order Summary" when the customer returns to you site after customer puts in their payment details on paypal.  At which point the customer presses "confirm" and then you tell paypal to process the charge and you do whatever type of "thank you page" you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paypal [Invoicing API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/invoicing/) which suite your requirement. 
2nd and best option is [Express CheckOut](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/)

If you have something like recurring payment you can use stripe Payment gateways which is quite easy and mostly used in apps.

Answer (score 0):

Your point of integration should be the invoice not the payment. If you utilize 3rd party service, you'll obtain a far more complete solution which will be better tailor made for your Healthcare application. Try this free service: http://www.billiving.com/Signup/PayPal